# In Direct Payment CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile give 10001 error with timeout

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox

I have used nvr...

```
$date=strtotime(date('Y-m-d')); // if today :2013-05-23
$newDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+30 days',$date));
$startdate=urlencode($newDate."T0:0:0");

$nvpstr="&CREDITCARDTYPE=".$creditCardType;
$nvpstr.="&ACCT=".$creditCardNumber;
$nvpstr.="&EXPDATE=".$expDate;
$nvpstr.="&FIRSTNAME=".$shipToCity;
$nvpstr.="&LASTNAME=".$shipToState;
$nvpstr.="&PROFILESTARTDATE=".$startdate;
$nvpstr.="&DESC=".urlencode("Test Recurring Payment(".$recAMT." monthly)");
$nvpstr.="&BILLINGPERIOD=Month";
$nvpstr.="&BILLINGFREQUENCY=1";
$nvpstr.="&AMT=".$recAMT;
$nvpstr.="&EMAIL=".$email;
$nvpstr.="&STREET=".$street;
$nvpstr.="&ZIP=".$zip;
$nvpstr.="&STATE=".$state;
$nvpstr.="&COUNTRY=".$countryCode;
$nvpstr.="&PHONENUM=".$phonenum;
$nvpstr.="&SHIPTONAME=".$shipname;
$nvpstr.="&SHIPTOSTREET=".$shipstreet;
$nvpstr.="&SHIPTOCITY=".$shipcity;
$nvpstr.="&SHIPTOSTATE=".$shipstate;
$nvpstr.="&SHIPTOZIP=".$shipzip;
$nvpstr.="&SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=".$shipcountryCode;
$nvpstr.="&SHIPTOPHONENUM=".$shipphonenum;


$resArray=hash_call("CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile",$nvpstr);
```

Its gives the following error...

```
array(6) { ["TIMESTAMP"]=> string(20) "2013-09-21T17:52:15Z" 
           ["CORRELATIONID"]=> string(12) "c52f31b51d48" 
           ["ACK"]=> string(7) "Failure" 
           ["L_ERRORCODE0"]=> string(5) "10001" 
           ["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"]=> string(14) "Internal Error" 
           ["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]=> string(26) "Timeout processing request" 
         }
```